# Is Bing speech to text & PCI

Tags: speech-to-text, bing, speech, azure-cognitive-services, pci-compliance

For work purposes I would like to deploy and app using Bing speech to text, but I'm being asked does the backend infrastructure have PCI certification,. Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question? What does it have do to with programming?

Comment: my question is would the Microsoft end of an app using bing speech to text be PCI compliant; but your right, not really a programming question, more on the infrastructure/security side, although a question a programmer working in this area might be able to shed some light on...I'll continue my quest elsewhere, thanks!

Comment: There is absolutely no way sending PCI data (i.e. credit card numbers) to Bing would be permissible.

Comment: Bing Speech is a deprecated service, the new Microsoft Azure Speech Service is PCI compliant (type the following in your browser: aka.ms/azurecompliance).